# How to extract all dataframes from this list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract

I´m trying to extract the values from this list from each matrix as computed below:

By following the documentation available in https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/BVAR/html/irf.bvar.html

```
library(BVAR)

# Access a subset of the fred_qd dataset
data <- fred_qd[, c("CPIAUCSL", "UNRATE", "FEDFUNDS")]
# Transform it to be stationary
data <- fred_transform(data, codes = c(5, 5, 1), lag = 4)

# Estimate a BVAR using one lag, default settings and very few draws
x <- bvar(data, lags = 1, n_draw = 600L, n_burn = 100L, verbose = FALSE)
```

Now computing de impulse-response function:

```
# Compute + store IRF with a longer horizon, no identification and thinning
irf(x) <- irf(x, bv_irf(horizon = 24L, identification = FALSE), n_thin = 5L)

# Update the confidence bands of the IRFs
irf(x, conf_bands = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1))
Impulse response object from `bvar()`.
Horizon: 24
Identification: FALSE
FEVD: FALSE
Variables: 3
Iterations: 100

# Recalculate with sign restrictions provided via the ellipsis
irf(x, sign_restr = matrix(c(1, NA, NA, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1), nrow = 3))
Impulse response object from `bvar()`.
Horizon: 12
Identification: Sign restrictions
Chosen restrictions:
            Shock to
             Var1    Var2    Var3    
Response of Var1     +   -   -  

        Var2     NA  +   +  

        Var3     NA  -   +  
FEVD: FALSE
Variables: 3
Iterations: 500

# Recalculate with zero and sign restrictions provided via the ellipsis
irf(x, sign_restr = matrix(c(1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1), nrow = 3))
Impulse response object from `bvar()`.
Horizon: 12
Identification: Sign restrictions
Chosen restrictions:
            Shock to
             Var1    Var2    Var3    
Response of Var1     +   NA  -  

        Var2     0   +   -  

        Var3     +   +   +  
FEVD: FALSE
Variables: 3
Iterations: 500
```

And finally I need to extract the FEVD:

```
# Calculate the forecast error variance decomposition
str(fevd(x))
List of 3
 $ fevd     : num [1:500, 1:3, 1:12, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variables: chr [1:3] "CPIAUCSL" "UNRATE" "FEDFUNDS"
 $ quants   : num [1:3, 1:3, 1:12, 1:3] 1 1 1 0.0655 0.0939 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "16%" "50%" "84%"
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "bvar_fevd"

fevd(x)$quants
```

And then this is the output:

```
, , 1, 1

    [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16%    1 0.06554894 0.05240534
50%    1 0.09385399 0.07403429
84%    1 0.12069017 0.10156270

, , 2, 1

         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16% 0.9981355 0.05959117 0.06601553
50% 0.9953126 0.08630489 0.08863040
84% 0.9907278 0.11379294 0.11646042

, , 3, 1

         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16% 0.9949724 0.05470677 0.07833166
50% 0.9873854 0.08199506 0.10081997
84% 0.9757015 0.10807056 0.12815205

, , 4, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9913594 0.05109522 0.0882190
50% 0.9781148 0.07682589 0.1104896
84% 0.9589753 0.10411274 0.1378231

, , 5, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9875275 0.04970876 0.0946325
50% 0.9686025 0.07416360 0.1178439
84% 0.9414501 0.10106295 0.1466201

, , 6, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9834937 0.05022273 0.1014418
50% 0.9600395 0.07348178 0.1248863
84% 0.9262575 0.09989520 0.1549010

, , 7, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9799866 0.05133221 0.1054734
50% 0.9521135 0.07442128 0.1299256
84% 0.9116995 0.09997616 0.1617301

, , 8, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9753857 0.05381045 0.1094240
50% 0.9442310 0.07637673 0.1350156
84% 0.8993103 0.10132729 0.1672287

, , 9, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9725864 0.05659012 0.1117643
50% 0.9370791 0.07873632 0.1392836
84% 0.8861691 0.10350582 0.1704144

, , 10, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9693344 0.06128344 0.1141581
50% 0.9306585 0.08347832 0.1418052
84% 0.8744522 0.10613979 0.1750562

, , 11, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9673858 0.06475636 0.1146911
50% 0.9235790 0.08658795 0.1445193
84% 0.8647600 0.11093085 0.1776345

, , 12, 1

         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
16% 0.9642122 0.06769502 0.1141264
50% 0.9186276 0.09055297 0.1472476
84% 0.8574439 0.11433712 0.1820168

, , 1, 2

    [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
16%    0 0.9344511 0.01790358
50%    0 0.9061460 0.03320622
84%    0 0.8793098 0.05426475
```

I don´t know how to extract all matrix of this output as dataframes in R...

Comment: Can you please provide your output as `dput()`? For example, if your output is named `data`, run `dput(data)` and copy/paste the results.

Comment: using ```dput(fevd(x)$quants)``` the output is: ```structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0.0670363660954466, 0.0963648161850099, 0.123490716260723, 0.0501445041929837,...```

Answer (score 0):

As it is an array of 4D, it may be better to reshape into long and store as a single data.frame

```
ar1 <- fevd(x)$quants
dat <- reshape2::melt(ar1)
> dim(dat)
[1] 324   5
```

-output

```
> tail(dat)
    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4       value
319  16%    2   12    3 0.000824041
320  50%    2   12    3 0.006787208
321  84%    2   12    3 0.022790139
322  16%    3   12    3 0.654302911
323  50%    3   12    3 0.591934254
324  84%    3   12    3 0.551836024
```

---

Or if we want a `list` of `matrix`

```
lst1 <- lapply(asplit(expand.grid(seq(dim(ar1)[3]),
      seq(dim(ar1)[4])), 1), \(i)  ar1[,, i[1], i[2]] )
> lapply(lst1[1:3], head, 3)
[[1]]
    [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16%    1 0.06623276 0.04945730
50%    1 0.09592370 0.07418600
84%    1 0.12669767 0.09846717

[[2]]
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16% 0.9981086 0.05919055 0.06356320
50% 0.9948008 0.08906681 0.08961825
84% 0.9903040 0.12035394 0.11161847

[[3]]
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
16% 0.9949315 0.05481271 0.07518724
50% 0.9863161 0.08327069 0.10206451
84% 0.9745784 0.11442243 0.12435641
```